# Debug our SPFx web part inside VS Code inside a site collection workbench will not show the related web part

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, spfx, spfx-webparts, workbench

We are developing an SPFx web part, and using VS code & Chrome debugger extension >> I debug the code:-

[image]

and we specify to debug inside a hosted Workbench:-

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [

      {
        "name": "Hosted workbench",
        "type": "pwa-chrome",
        "request": "launch",
        "url": "https://****.sharepoint.com/teams/*****/_layouts/workbench.aspx",
        "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}",
        "sourceMaps": true,
        "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
          "webpack:///.././src/*": "${webRoot}/src/*",
          "webpack:///../../../src/*": "${webRoot}/src/*",
          "webpack:///../../../../src/*": "${webRoot}/src/*",
          "webpack:///../../../../../src/*": "${webRoot}/src/*"
        },
        "runtimeArgs": [
          "--remote-debugging-port=9222",
          "-incognito"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

but when we start debugging >> and  we edit the https://****.sharepoint.com/teams/*****/_layouts/workbench.aspx page >> the SPFX web part we are developing will not appear inside the web parts list, as follow:-

[image]

now inside VS code , i found the following errors/exceptions inside the debug console:-

```
Uncaught Error Error: Failed to create application customizer 'ClientSideExtension.ApplicationCustomizer.1b3557f3-315d-4187-8d58-60e88e93d654'. Error information is 'Extension failed to initialize for componentId "1b3557f3-315d-4187-8d58-60e88e93d654".'.
    at <anonymous> (https://res-1.cdn.office.net/files/sp-client/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_en-us_5733dc04dc3fe6c1857afd79874c8501.js:72:653421)
    --- Promise.then ---
    at e.loadExtensions (https://res-1.cdn.office.net/files/sp-client/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_en-us_5733dc04dc3fe6c1857afd79874c8501.js:72:651721)
    at e._loadApplicationCustomizers (https://res-1.cdn.office.net/files/sp-client/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_en-us_5733dc04dc3fe6c1857afd79874c8501.js:72:661449)
    at <anonymous> (https://res-1.cdn.office.net/files/sp-client/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_en-us_5733dc04dc3fe6c1857afd79874c8501.js:72:661027)
    --- Promise.then ---
    at e.navigate (https://res-1.cdn.office.net/files/sp-client/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_en-us_5733dc04dc3fe6c1857afd79874c8501.js:72:660940)
    at e.navigateToApplication (https://res-1.cdn.office.net/files/sp-client/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_en-us_5733dc04dc3fe6c1857afd79874c8501.js:72:668615)
    at c (https://res-1.cdn.office.net/files/sp-client/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_en-us_5733dc04dc3fe6c1857afd79874c8501.js:72:78396)
    at <anonymous> (https://res-1.cdn.office.net/files/sp-client/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_en-us_5733dc04dc3fe6c1857afd79874c8501.js:72:78215)
    at s (https://res-1.cdn.office.net/files/sp-client/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_en-us_5733dc04dc3fe6c1857afd79874c8501.js:72:77814)
    at e._startApplication (https://res-1.cdn.office.net/files/sp-client/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_en-us_5733dc04dc3fe6c1857afd79874c8501.js:72:57468)
    at e._startApplication (https://res-1.cdn.office.net/files/sp-client/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_en-us_5733dc04dc3fe6c1857afd79874c8501.js:72:18238)
    at <anonymous> (https://res-1.cdn.office.net/files/sp-client/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_en-us_5733dc04dc3fe6c1857afd79874c8501.js:72:72370)
    --- Promise.then ---
    at e.start (https://res-1.cdn.office.net/files/sp-client/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_en-us_5733dc04dc3fe6c1857afd79874c8501.js:72:71932)
    at loaderStart (https://sharing365.sharepoint.com/teams/ViewDocsTestSite/_layouts/15/workbench.aspx:57:74)
    at startSpfx (https://sharing365.sharepoint.com/teams/ViewDocsTestSite/_layouts/15/workbench.aspx:69:29)
    at <anonymous> (https://sharing365.sharepoint.com/teams/ViewDocsTestSite/_layouts/15/workbench.aspx:96:21)
    at <anonymous> (https://sharing365.sharepoint.com/teams/ViewDocsTestSite/_layouts/15/workbench.aspx:100:15)


Uncaught Error Error: Script error for: http://localhost:4321/temp/manifests.js
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
    at B (<eval>/VM46947589:8:252)
    at onScriptError (<eval>/VM46947589:30:244)
    --- error ---
    at e.load (<eval>/VM46947589:34:344)
    at load (<eval>/VM46947589:29:498)
    at load (<eval>/VM46947589:18:85)
    at fetch (<eval>/VM46947589:18:24)
    at check (<eval>/VM46947589:20:36)
    at enable (<eval>/VM46947589:23:439)
    at enable (<eval>/VM46947589:28:172)
    at eval (<eval>/VM46947589:23:311)
    at eval (<eval>/VM46947589:8:102)
    at v (<eval>/VM46947589:7:173)
    at enable (<eval>/VM46947589:22:343)
    at init (<eval>/VM46947589:17:108)
    at eval (<eval>/VM46947589:27:38)
    --- setTimeout ---
    at e.nextTick (<eval>/VM46947589:32:308)
    at g (<eval>/VM46947589:26:490)
    at requirejs (<eval>/VM46947589:32:203)
    at <anonymous> (https://res-1.cdn.office.net/files/sp-client/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_en-us_5733dc04dc3fe6c1857afd79874c8501.js:72:67093)
    at e._require (https://res-1.cdn.office.net/files/sp-client/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_en-us_5733dc04dc3fe6c1857afd79874c8501.js:72:67065)
    at <anonymous> (https://res-1.cdn.office.net/files/sp-client/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_en-us_5733dc04dc3fe6c1857afd79874c8501.js:72:63744)
    at e.load (https://res-1.cdn.office.net/files/sp-client/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_en-us_5733dc04dc3fe6c1857afd79874c8501.js:72:63669)
    at e.loadScript (https://res-1.cdn.office.net/files/sp-client/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_en-us_5733dc04dc3fe6c1857afd79874c8501.js:72:63576)
    at e.loadScript (https://res-1.cdn.office.net/files/sp-client/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_en-us_5733dc04dc3fe6c1857afd79874c8501.js:72:57175)
    at e.loadAndRegisterManifestsFile (https://res-1.cdn.office.net/files/sp-client/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_en-us_5733dc04dc3fe6c1857afd79874c8501.js:72:12303)
    at e._loadDebugManifestsForWorkbench (https://res-1.cdn.office.net/files/sp-client/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_en-us_5733dc04dc3fe6c1857afd79874c8501.js:72:57367)
    at e._loadDebugManifestsForWorkbench (https://res-1.cdn.office.net/files/sp-client/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_en-us_5733dc04dc3fe6c1857afd79874c8501.js:72:19161)
    at <anonymous> (https://res-1.cdn.office.net/files/sp-client/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_en-us_5733dc04dc3fe6c1857afd79874c8501.js:72:1588064)
    --- Promise.catch ---
    at n (https://res-1.cdn.office.net/files/sp-client/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_en-us_5733dc04dc3fe6c1857afd79874c8501.js:72:1588024)
    at t.onLoad (https://res-1.cdn.office.net/files/sp-client/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_en-us_5733dc04dc3fe6c1857afd79874c8501.js:72:1588126)
    at t._load (https://res-1.cdn.office.net/files/sp-client/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_en-us_5733dc04dc3fe6c1857afd79874c8501.js:72:676559)
    at e._initializeApplication (https://res-1.cdn.office.net/files/sp-client/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_en-us_5733dc04dc3fe6c1857afd79874c8501.js:72:674274)
    at e._initializeApplicationWithTelemetry (https://res-1.cdn.office.net/files/sp-client/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_en-us_5733dc04dc3fe6c1857afd79874c8501.js:72:672798)
    at e.startApplication (https://res-1.cdn.office.net/files/sp-client/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_en-us_5733dc04dc3fe6c1857afd79874c8501.js:72:672205)
    at e.navigate (https://res-1.cdn.office.net/files/sp-client/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_en-us_5733dc04dc3fe6c1857afd79874c8501.js:72:660920)
    at e.navigateToApplication (https://res-1.cdn.office.net/files/sp-client/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_en-us_5733dc04dc3fe6c1857afd79874c8501.js:72:668615)
    at c (https://res-1.cdn.office.net/files/sp-client/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_en-us_5733dc04dc3fe6c1857afd79874c8501.js:72:78396)
    at <anonymous> (https://res-1.cdn.office.net/files/sp-client/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_en-us_5733dc04dc3fe6c1857afd79874c8501.js:72:78215)
    at s (https://res-1.cdn.office.net/files/sp-client/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_en-us_5733dc04dc3fe6c1857afd79874c8501.js:72:77814)
    at e._startApplication (https://res-1.cdn.office.net/files/sp-client/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_en-us_5733dc04dc3fe6c1857afd79874c8501.js:72:57468)
    at e._startApplication (https://res-1.cdn.office.net/files/sp-client/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_en-us_5733dc04dc3fe6c1857afd79874c8501.js:72:18238)
    at <anonymous> (https://res-1.cdn.office.net/files/sp-client/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_en-us_5733dc04dc3fe6c1857afd79874c8501.js:72:72370)
    --- Promise.then ---
    at e.start (https://res-1.cdn.office.net/files/sp-client/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_en-us_5733dc04dc3fe6c1857afd79874c8501.js:72:71932)
    at loaderStart (https://sharing365.sharepoint.com/teams/ViewDocsTestSite/_layouts/15/workbench.aspx:57:74)
    at startSpfx (https://sharing365.sharepoint.com/teams/ViewDocsTestSite/_layouts/15/workbench.aspx:69:29)
    at <anonymous> (https://sharing365.sharepoint.com/teams/ViewDocsTestSite/_layouts/15/workbench.aspx:96:21)
    at <anonymous> (https://sharing365.sharepoint.com/teams/ViewDocsTestSite/_layouts/15/workbench.aspx:100:15)
Could not read source map for https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=89bee1f7-5e6e-4d8a-9f3d-ecd601259da7&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwebshell.suite.office.com%2F.default%20openid%20profile%20offline_access&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwebshell.suite.office.com%2Fiframe%2FTokenFactoryIframe&client-request-id=d4384575-e83d-40b7-aed0-5b5309443ded&response_mode=fragment&response_type=code&x-client-SKU=msal.js.browser&x-client-VER=2.17.0&x-client-OS=&x-client-CPU=&client_info=1&code_challenge=5_EnnfzFx4E6BojcrF-sekI8EWIDJFzxaPjkDeqGoEg&code_challenge_method=S256&prompt=none&login_hint=development%40sharing365.io&X-AnchorMailbox=UPN%3Adevelopment%40sharing365.io&nonce=1b145f6f-bc3e-4a0f-8584-50132ac07324&state=eyJpZCI6IjQwM2UzOWI4LWMxOGMtNGFkYS1iMjQyLWM5NGI5OTk4ODdjMiIsIm1ldGEiOnsiaW50ZXJhY3Rpb25UeXBlIjoic2lsZW50In19: Unexpected 404 response from https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/oauth2/v2.0/0c8a0f745d41df706649.map: 
BSSO Telemetry: {"result":"Error","error":"NoExtension","type":"ChromeSsoTelemetry","data":{},"traces":["BrowserSSO Initialized","Creating ChromeBrowserCore provider","Sending message for method CreateProviderAsync","Received message for method CreateProviderAsync","Error: ChromeBrowserCore error NoExtension: Extension is not installed."]}
login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=89bee1f7-5e6e-4d8a-9f3d-ecd601259da7&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwebshell.suite.office.com%2F.default+openid+profile+offline_access&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwebshell.suite.office.com%2Fiframe%2FTokenFactoryIframe&client-request-id=d4384575-e83d-40b7-aed0-5b5309443ded&response_mode=fragment&response_type=code&x-client-SKU=msal.js.browser&x-client-VER=2.17.0&x-client-OS=&x-client-CPU=&client_info=1&code_challenge=5_EnnfzFx4E6BojcrF-sekI8EWIDJFzxaPjkDeqGoEg&code_challenge_method=S256&prompt=none&login_hint=development%40sharing365.io&X-AnchorMailbox=UPN%3Adevelopment%40sharing365.io&nonce=1b145f6f-bc3e-4a0f-8584-50132ac07324&state=eyJpZCI6IjQwM2UzOWI4LWMxOGMtNGFkYS1iMjQyLWM5NGI5OTk4ODdjMiIsIm1ldGEiOnsiaW50ZXJhY3Rpb25UeXBlIjoic2lsZW50In19꞉56:32:74
Some icons were re-registered. Applications should only call registerIcons for any given icon once. Redefining what an icon is may have unintended consequences. Duplicates include: 
GraphSymbol, GraphSymbol, GraphSymbol, GraphSymbol, GraphSymbol, GraphSymbol, GraphSymbol, GraphSymbol, GraphSymbol, GraphSymbol (+ 167 more)
```

Also when we access the workbench >> we will get this message, although we are already running/debugging the project inside VS code:-

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this could solve your problem or not but I am sharing my experience when I faced similar kind of situation.

> Problem : Spfx webpart is not appearing
> https://siteURL/_layouts/workbench.aspx

> Solution : Open the URL on same browser tab that opens by default
> using gulp serve

So I always use gulp serve to open the workbench ( localhost)and in the same browser tab , open the https://siteURL/_layouts/workbench.aspx

Comment: i am not using the gulp serve .. i am debugging the project directly using visual studio'

Comment: Sorry couldn't help you.Looking forward to answers without gulp serve.

Comment: do you mean i need to use gulp serve ?

Comment: also when i tired `Gulp serve` i got this error: - `No gulpfile found`

Comment: First you need to sort out this error of No gulp file , once all good then try debugging project in VS